# cvCreateFileCapture causing segmentation fault error on Arm Linux Pandaboard

Tags: linux, opencv

I have installed `Linux3.1.0-1282-omap4 armv71` & `Opencv 2.4.9` with neon optimizations on `pandaboard`.
Sample code :

```
int main()
{
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture("C:/OpenCV2.1/samples/c/tree.avi");

    IplImage* frame = NULL;

    if(!capture)
    {
        printf("Video Not Opened\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int width = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    int height = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    double fps = cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    int frame_count = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture,  CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);

    printf("Video Size = %d x %d\n",width,height);
    printf("FPS = %f\nTotal Frames = %d\n",fps,frame_count);

    while(1)
    {
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

        if(!frame)
        {
            printf("Capture Finished\n");
            break;
        }

        cvShowImage("video",frame);
        cvWaitKey(10);
    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles without any error, 
but when I run my program , It shows `segmentation fault error`

I had also commented all the code except this line:
  `CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture("C:/OpenCV2.1/samples/c/tree.avi");`
to check that may it be causing error ?, but It still throws a `segmentation fault` error.

Thanks

Comment: aww, you're really trying with opencv2.1 ? that's far too old. also i guess, there's no "C:/" at all on your arm board, so the path does not exist

Comment: I am using opencv-2.4.9 on Linux arm

Comment: also try to avoid the deprecated c-api in favour of c++

Comment: depreciated c api also works. this is not an issue.